# Output characters from the clipboard one-by-one, as if typing

Tags: windows-10, clipboard, keyboard

I can not find a program for Windows 10. I would like to dump the entire contents of the clipboard (Ctrl + V).

character - delay - character - delay - character - etc..
Something like a typewriter. Use into all programs .. Mainly to the command line.

Answer (score 3):

**AutoHotkey** is the perfect program for this:
https://autohotkey.com/download/

The script for this in AutoHotkey would be something like:

```
^j::
   Send, %clipboard%
Return
```

When this script is running, hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> would retype the contents of your keyboard wherever you are.

---

I don't think I can give you exact instructions, there are a lot of guides out there, and their help is pretty straight forward for simple things like this one:

[AutoHotkey Beginner Tutorial](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm#s1)